# How can programming this checkbox in select dropdown?

Tags: php, html, laravel-5

[this what i need make dynamic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWiRp.png)I am new to Laravel and need help in programming this checkbox in select dropdown.

**my html form**

```
    <div class="container w60">
    <div class="row pad_y_20">

        <div class="col s12">
                <h3 class="c_black center-align bold">Search for Our Products</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="input-field my_arrow col s12 m10 push-m1 l3" >
            <select multiple>
          <option value="" disabled selected>Properties</option>
          <option value="1">Option 1</option>
          <option value="2">Option 2</option>
          <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field my_arrow col s12 m10 push-m1 l3">
            <select multiple>
          <option value="" disabled selected>Target animals</option>
          <option value="1">Option 1</option>
          <option value="2">Option 2</option>
          <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div class="input-field my_arrow col s12 m10 push-m1 l3">
            <select multiple>
          <option value="" disabled selected>Form</option>
          <option value="1">Option 1</option>
          <option value="2">Option 2</option>
          <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col s12 m10 push-m1 l3">
            <a href="/search" class="waves-effect waves-light w100 btn-large marg_y_5">Search</a>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**my database table**

[image]

Thanks a lot for helping. I need php code or Laravel.

Comment: It's not clear what your goal is. Where is the checkbox? What problem got you stuck? please edit your answer with a better explaination

Comment: my goal i need to make this select and checkbox dynamic with laravel the picture in link in begining of question.

Comment: Do you already have Product model? Are you passing some objects to the blade template?

Comment: yes i have Product model. and i need to know what objects can pass to blade template and how?

Answer (score 0):

In your Controller, you can pass object to the blade template:

```
$products = Product::get();
return view('your.blade.view')->with([
    'products' => $products
});
```

Then in your blade template file you can use them:

```
<select multiple name="property">
    @foreach($products as $product)
        <option value="{{ $product->id }}"> {{ $product->name }} </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

This is an example, you need to tweak this code to satisfy your needs but it should be the right track to follow

Comment: Excuse me also i need when checked and press on search button return to result view and view all data checked.

Answer (score -1):

This php code may help

```
<?php
//connect to your database here
require_once("../core/init.php");

//query database
$q_property = $db->query(("select properties from products2"));
$q_animal = $db->query(("select animal_id from products2"));
$q_form = $db->query(("select form from products2"));
?>
<div class="row pad_y_20">
  <div class="col s12">
            <h3 class="c_black center-align bold">Search for Our 
Products</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field my_arrow col s12 m10 push-m1 l3" >
        <select multiple name="property">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Properties</option>
      <?php
      //we  loop over each property value and echo it to our select input
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($q_property)){

        $property = $row[0];
       ?>
      <option value="<?= $property ?>"><?= $property ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field my_arrow col s12 m10 push-m1 l3">
        <select multiple name="target_animal">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Target animals</option>
      <?php
        //we  loop over each animal_id value and echo it to our select input
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($q_animal)){

        $animal = $row[0];
       ?>
      <option value="<?= $animal ?>"><?= $animal ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="input-field my_arrow col s12 m10 push-m1 l3">
        <select multiple name="form">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Form</option>
      <?php
        //we  loop over each form value and echo it to our select input
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($q_form)){
        $form = $row[0];
       ?>
      <option value="<?= $form ?>"><?= $form ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m10 push-m1 l3">
        <input type="submit" value="search"/a>
    </div>

 </div>
 </div>
```

[Check this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGmXY.png)

Comment: This is not laravel